# Need to know if I am using IF statements in stored procedures correctly in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am pretty amateur to PL/SQL, and I do not know if I am using the IF statements correctly. I am using Oracle Live SQL. This is all trying to insert a new row into a table called 'employees'. And the only NOT NULL values are employeeid, employeename, and jobid

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE employees.insert_employee
(
    p_employeeid            employees.employeeid%TYPE,
    p_employeename          employees.employeename%TYPE,
    p_phone                 employees.phone%TYPE,
    p_jobid                 employees.jobid%TYPE,
    p_salary                employees.salary%TYPE,
    p_managerid             employees.managerid%TYPE,
    p_departmentid          employees.departmentid%TYPE
) 

AS
BEGIN
    IF p_employeeid IS NULL THEN /* If one of the mandatory values are null */
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    IF p_employeename IS NULL THEN 
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    IF p_jobid IS NULL THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    IF p_jobid != employees.jobid THEN /* if jobid entered is not in the table */
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    IF p_salary < 0 THEN /* if the entered salary is negative */
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    IF p_departmentid != employees.departmentid THEN /* if the departmentid entered is not in the table */
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;

    IF p.employeeid = employees.employeeid THEN /* if the employeeid already exists */
        RAISE RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2000);
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO employees (employeeid, employeename, phone, jobid, salary, managerid, departmentid)
    VALUES(p_employeeid, p_employeename, p_phone, p_jobid, p_salary, p_managerid, p_departmentid);

END;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the IF statements.  The user you are logged in as may not have the rights to compile the procedure or possibly insert into the table

Comment: Are the IF statements being used correctly though, that's what I'm wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it would even compile. Besides, you shouldn't do it that way (as you were already told). A few more objections, if I may (regarding the original question: whether you use `IF` correctly).

Bunch of first `IF`s can be shortened with `OR`:

```
IF p_employeeid   IS NULL OR
   p_employeename IS NULL OR
   p_jobid        IS NULL OR
   p_salary < 0 
THEN
    RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
END IF;
```

---

You can't reference table values that way, e.g.

```
IF p_jobid != employees.jobid THEN /* if jobid entered is not in the table */
    RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
END IF;
```

There's no `employees.jobid` - you have to select it first. For example:

```
declare
  l_cnt;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from employees e
    where e.jobid = p_jobid;

  if l_cnt = 0 then     -- there's no such job in the table
     raise value_error;
  end if;
end;
```

---

Finally, the *final* condition you checked and tried to *raise something*

```
RAISE RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2000);
```

is wrong for 3 reasons:

- you don't `RAISE RAISE_...`
- User defined exception's range is from `-20001` to `-20999` (five digits, not 4)
- `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` requires yet another argument

so - correctly - you'd

```
raise_application_error(-20001, 'That does not exist');
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if the syntax is right, I don't think you are using them correctly.

1) If things should not be allowed to be null then mark them as `NOT NULL` on the tables.

2) If the departmentID must exist then that's a foreign key constraint.

3) If the employeeID exists that should be a unique constraint (even if your syntax works, which it does not)

Properly declared, the DB engine will ensure all this for you.